# How to convert json into jackson

Tags: json, jackson, iot

i am an electrical engineering student and programming is new to me,I am asking the above stated question because i am working on my minor project in IOT technology and getting issues related to these topic.

Comment: the wiki gives a pretty good tutorial http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: This question is way too broad... Have you read the [`jackson-databind`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) project documentation? It's a great way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an [ObjectMapper configured](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/practical-jackson-objectmapper-configuration).

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, TypeReference<T> typeRef) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JsonException(e);
    }
}
```

You can call it with

```
Message message = Json.serializer().fromJson(rawJson, new TypeReference<Message>() {});
```